# How can I track down the cause of a duplicate key exception during a binaryformatter deserialization?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, deserialization, binaryformatter

While trying to deserialize a file created by a BinaryFormatter, the following exception is thrown:

**ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.**

The stack trace starts at the Deserialize method in BinaryFormatter, and I cannot identify what class in my code is causing the collision.

I am serializing 100+ classes marked with the **[Serializable]** attribute

I saw another question suggesting that the cause might be related to fields having duplicate names. However, I cannot find the collision causing field among the 100+ classes and don't know of a more efficient way to track it down besides combing through the code by hand.

Is there a better way to start debugging this issue besides going over field in every class by hand? Is there perhaps a different cause for the collision in the first place? I greatly appreciate any insight into this issue that can be provided.

**Exception Contents**

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  Message=An item with the same key has already been added.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.OnDeserialization(Object sender)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DeserializationEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.RaiseDeserializationEvent()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
   at SPX.Saves.Save`1.Read() in .\SPX.Save\Save.cs:line 42
   at OGUR.States.MainMenuState.Update() in .\OGUR\OGUR\States\MainMenuState.cs:line 64
   at SPX.States.StateManager.Update() in .\SPX.States\StateManager.cs:line 30
   at OGUR.Game.Update(GameTime gameTime) in .\OGUR\OGUR\Game.cs:line 63
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Tick()
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.HostIdle(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameHost.OnIdle()
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.WindowsGameHost.RunOneFrame()
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.WindowsGameHost.ApplicationIdle(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponent.FDoIdle(Int32 grfidlef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.WindowsGameHost.Run()
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.RunGame(Boolean useBlockingRun)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Run()
   at OGUR.EntryPoint.Main(String[] args) in .\OGUR\OGUR\EntryPoint.cs:line 15
InnerException:
```

Comment: We will need more information in order to help you. Did you implement custom serialization on some classes? Do you have control over the serialization process(guess you do)? May be attach the exception data. Ultimately you will have to try to serialize each class alone in order to narrow the fields of search.

Comment: @Sahuagin unfortunately, there is no inner exception

Comment: @lcfseth In three classes I used the [NonSerializable] attribute on some fields. One class (SaveData) implements ISerializable, and is the DTO between the application and what is serialized to disk. I own the entire code base.

Comment: So all serialization must pass through the SaveData class? Did you implement a custom constructor (You should have)? This can be a great help for debugging. Can you attach the constructor code (a compressed version of it), and eventually the Exception data.

Comment: After realizing that SaveData has no special needs for serialization, I removed its implementation of ISerializable and instead applied the [Serializable] attribute. The same exception is still being thrown.

Comment: Look at the locals with the debugger. At the top frame. That will give you the key name. Then move down the callstack to find out what object is causing the problem.